The construction of Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure
In Proposition 1.15 Folland's book Real Analysis, we need to check that the map $\mu_0$ is a pre-measure. It seems that I gave an alternate proof of part of the proposition, which is a liitle bit more concise than the one in the book. But I'm not sure whether it is correct.
Let me rephrase what I need to prove.
Proposition. Suppose that
$$
\bigsqcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} (a_n, b_n] = (a, b],
$$
where $ - \infty \le a_\bullet < b_\bullet < + \infty $, and that $ F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ right continuous and increasing. then
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (F(b_n) - F(a_n)) = F(b) - F(a).
$$
My Proof. Since $ b \in \bigsqcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} (a_n, b_n] $, there exists a unique $ n \in \mathbb{Z}_+ $, such that $ b \in (a_n, b_n] $. Thus $ b \le b_n $. Since $ b_n \in (a, b] $, we know that $ b_n \le b $. Apriori $ b = b_n $. WLOG, we may assume that $ b = b_1 $. Then
$$
\bigsqcup_{n = 2}^{\infty} (a_n, b_n] = (a, b] - (a_1, b_1] = (a, a_1].
$$
With the same reason, we may assume that $ a_1 = b_2 $. Repeat this process, we may assume that $ a_n = b_{n + 1}, \ \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$. Hence
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (F(b_n) - F(a_n))
 = & \
 \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n = 1}^{N} (F(b_n) - F(a_n)) \\
 = & \
 \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n = 1}^{N} (F(b_n) - F(b_{n + 1})) \\
 = & \
 \lim_{N \to \infty} (F(b_1) - F(b_{N + 1})) \\
 = & \
 F(b_1) - \lim_{N \to \infty} F(b_{N + 1}).
\end{align*}
It is easy to show that $ b_{N + 1} = a_{N} \to a $ as $ N \to \infty $. Hence with the right-continuity of $F$, we complete the proof.
I wonder if there are any essential mistakes in the proof above. Thank you for taking time to read.

This proof is wrong. Provided that we write down the proof in a more precise way, we will find where the problem is:
Since $ b \in \bigsqcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} (a_n, b_n] $, there exists a unique $ n_0 \in \mathbb{Z}_+ $, such that $ b \in (a_{n_0}, b_{n_0}] $. Thus $ b \le b_{n_0} $. Since $ b_{n_0} \in (a, b] $, we know that $ b_{n_0} \le b $. Apriori $ b = b_{n_0} $. Then:
$$
\bigsqcup_{n \ne n_0} (a_n, b_n] = (a, a_{n_0}].
$$
Then there is a unique $ n_1 \in \mathbb{Z}_{+} $, such that $ b_{n_1} = a_{n_0} $. Repeat this process, we may find a sequence
$$
b_{n_0} > b_{n_1} > b_{n_2} > \cdots
$$
such that $ b_{n_{k + 1}} = a_{n_k} $. However, this is not a rearrangement of $\{ b_n \}_n$, but a subsequence $ \{ b_{n_k} \}_{k} $. Hence we can not assure that
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} b_{n_k} = \lim_{k \to \infty} a_{n_{k - 1}} = a.
$$
For example, let us consider
$$
I_1 := \bigg( \frac{1}{2}, 1 \bigg], \ I_2 := \bigg( \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{2} \bigg], \ I_3 := \bigg( \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{3} \bigg], \cdots
$$
and
$$
J_1 := \bigg( 1 + \frac{1}{2}, 2 \bigg], \ J_2 := \bigg( 1 + \frac{1}{3}, 1 + \frac{1}{2} \bigg], \ J_3 := \bigg( 1 + \frac{1}{4}, 1 + \frac{1}{3} \bigg], \cdots
$$
Then
$$
\bigsqcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} \bigsqcup_{m = 1}^{\infty} I_n \sqcup J_m = (0, 2],
$$
but if we pick $\{ b_{n_k} \}_k$ as above from $\{ I_n, J_m \}_{n, m}$, we may only get $\{ J_m \}_m$ instead of $\{ I_n, J_m \}_{n, m}$.
That is why Folland chose such a complicated proof in his book. Loosely speaking, the "proof" I gave above is too concise to be correct.
